# Brake light switch clicky

Tags: brakes, mazda-3

Mazda 3 2017 with 21,000 miles.

The brake light switch ( brake relay switch ) seems to be a bit clicky and slightly stiff ( doesn't move in and out smoothly)

Any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: Do you mean the switch on the pedal that senses when the pedal is pressed down, or something else? Is this something that just started happening?

Comment: Yes the switch which activates the brake lights when you press the pedal down. It has always been like it since I purchased the car used at 20,000 miles

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is check whether the car's still under warranty, if it is let Mazda fix it as it's their responsibility. It is also worth checking your model for recall items, you never know what is a known problem with the type.

If warranty isn't an option then you need to determine if the problem is the switch or something else near the switch. Pull the switch off, you just twist it and it pops off, then use a flat bladed screwdriver to release the modular connector. Test the switch, if it's smooth and quiet then something else is going on and you need to check the assembly, maybe it needs lubrication or maybe there's an issue with the brake booster/master cylinder.

If the problem is the switch itself just replace it. The part's all of $15 or so, and given it's important safety equipment there's no good reason to mess around with it.

If replacing the switch isn't an option I would give it a close inspection, look for anything that's jammed in it. Press the switch plunger in and try to get some compressed air down the hole. Tap the switch on something solid at different angles, see if that helps. The last thing I would do is dab a small amount of silicone lube at the base of the switch plunger and exercise the plunger a few times. Whatever you try it's important to thoroughly test the switch to make sure it works before you drive.

Comment: Thank you. Yes the car is under warranty, do you think the warranty will cover this ? 
It is definitely the switch itself as if I push the plunger with my finger it is a bit sticky and not 100% smooth. Tried a bit of grease last week but made no difference. From what I know there is a spring mechanism after the plunger, and this is obviously a bit stiff so replacing it should sort it out. I'm good with cars but not willing to mess with it myself, so hopefully Mazda will replace the part as it's cheap and easy for them to diagnose.

Comment: It's absolutely a warranty issue, they should have no problem replacing a faulty brake light switch.

Comment: Mazda didn't want to know, they wanted to charge me £120 just to look at it. So I bought a genuine brand new brake light switch and it's identical to my current one. So looks as if I will live with it